# Stop batch process and jump to finish()

Tags: apex, batch

I have created a batch process and inside the `execute` function, there is a condition. If a condition is meet, I want to stop the `batch process` and then call another `batch process`.

What I am currently trying is to use the `System.abortJob()` function, and call the batch process in my finish function. But when the condition is met, the `abortJob()` will also stop the finish function being called, so I won't call the other `batch`. I also try to call my other `batch` before the `abortJob()` but I will get an error that I

> cannot call a batch process inside the execute function.

How can I fix my problem?